# CSS animate element with a dynamic max height

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

I've looked through quite a few posts and they are similar to what I need, but not quite and also it seems quite a few want to animate to a `max-height: auto`, which is not what I need.
Here's a picture of what I have:
[image]

List 1 is just 1 element long and has a 'sub list' to it. List 2 has currently got 2 elements within, but it is generated dynamically so it will have more in the future. To avoid list 2 being pushed off the screen when list 1 is expanded, I need to set a max height which I do like so:

```
let e = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-list-container")[0] as HTMLElement;
let e1 = document.getElementsByClassName("secondary-list")[0] as HTMLElement;

e.style.maxHeight = "calc(100% - " + e1.getBoundingClientRect().height + "px)"
```

I can't set this in the css because the height of list 2 changes so I can't just hard code a value.

For the animation of the drop down list I originally used `translateY`:

```css
.sub-list.slide-in {
    animation-name: slide-in;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes slide-in {
    from {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

and used `classList.add` to play the animation.
The issue is, although this creates a sliding effect with the content of the list, the actual height of list 1 is set to full instantly so it pushes list 2 to the bottom without it also being slid down.
The only way to get this effect I think is to animate max-height. To do so, I would need to animate it from max-height 0 to the dynamic height shown above. It would have to be `max-height: calc(100% - Ypx);` where Y is the height of list 2. Of course, you can't access attributes like that in css, so it has to be done in JS like above, but since it's in a keyframe, it's also very hard edit that.
A way to get a keyframe I found (and then change it) is like this:

```js
getRule() {
    var rule;
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {
        for (var x = 0; x < ss[i].cssRules.length; ++x) {
            rule = ss[i].cssRules[x];
            if (rule.name == "slide-in" && rule.type === CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE) {
                return rule;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However not only is this probably bad practise, it also errors for me:

```
Property 'cssRules' does not exist on type 'StyleSheet'.  TS2339
```

Even if it worked, after getting the rule you would need to edit it, and then add it back to the stylesheet which is quite slow.

Here's the actual JSX:

```
<IonList class="sub-list-container">
    <IonListHeader class="item list-header" lines="full">
        <IonLabel>Menu</IonLabel>
        <div className="ver-text">Version 1.0.0</div>
    </IonListHeader>
    {
        this.pages.map(p => {
            if (p.children?.length > 0) {
                return (
                    <>
                        <IonItem onClick={() => { this.update(p) }} class="item" style={{ "zIndex": "2" }} lines={p.open ? "none" : "inset"}>
                            {p.open ? <IonIcon slot="start" icon={chevronDownOutline} class="icons"></IonIcon> : <IonIcon slot="start" icon={chevronForwardOutline} class="icons"></IonIcon>}
                            <IonLabel>{p.title}</IonLabel>
                        </IonItem>

                        <IonList class="sub-list">
                            {p.open ? <IonMenuToggle autoHide={false} key={p.title}>
                                <IonItem></IonItem>
                                {
                                    p.children.map(el => el)
                                }
                            </IonMenuToggle> : ""}
                        </IonList>
                    </>
                );
            }
        })
    }
</IonList>
<IonList class="secondary-list">
    {
        this.pages.map(p => {
            if (p.children?.length === undefined) {
                return (
                    <IonMenuToggle autoHide={p.autoHide} key={p.title}>
                        <IonItem routerDirection="forward" routerLink={p.url} class="item">
                            <IonIcon slot="start" icon={p.icon}></IonIcon>
                            <IonLabel>{p.title}</IonLabel>
                        </IonItem>
                    </IonMenuToggle>
                )
            }
        })
    }
</IonList>
```

I would like to have `sub-list` move down (changing the height of it) while also pushing `secondary-list` down.

I've also tried animating `scaleY` which works but looks horrible.
I've tried just `height` but that's not possible. If anyone could help out that would be really appreciated

Comment: You can use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), and change them from JS, or you can use [JS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) to control the animation directly from the code.

Comment: Hi there, have you tried using height:max-content;

Comment: @OriDrori It seems the animate function is the best way to go. The issue now is that the keyframe / max-height does not seem to like the use of `calc`. If I put `max-height: 600px` it will animate very smoothly. The moment I use `"calc(100% - " + e1.getBoundingClientRect().height + "px)"`, the animation will just complete instantly.

Comment: You can measure the container height in is instead.

Comment: Yep it's all working now thanks! I'm not sure what I was thinking but I don't actually need to set the max-height in the animation dynamically. It can literally be 1000px but it's tyhe sub-list-container that needs the max-height. Either way, it's working now.